# How to get a random number without duplicate digits in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Update: The number can be started with zero.

I want to have a function like

```
function getRandomNumber(n){
  ...
}
```

I hope it gets a number with `n` digits while none of the digits is repeated. For instance:

```
getRandomNumber(3) -> 152 is what I want.
getRandomNumber(1) -> 6 is what I want.
getRandomNumber(6) -> 021598 is what I want. It can start with zero.
getRandomNumber(5) -> 23156 is what I want.
getRandomNumber(3) -> 252 is not because it has two 2.
getRandomNumber(5) -> 23153 is not because it has two 3.
```

Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On each call, make an array of digits, and then repeatedly pick random values and remove them from said array:

```js
function getRandomNumber(n){
  const digits = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i);
  const result = Array.from({ length: n }, () => {
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * digits.length);
    const digit = digits[randIndex];
    digits.splice(randIndex, 1);
    return digit;
  });
  return Number(result.join(''));
}


Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => console.log(getRandomNumber(8)));
```

Comment: Wow, Amazing solution! It returns a string so please `return Number(result.join())`.

Answer (score 1):

By keeping an array as an hash map, an efficient solution is as follows. However keep in mind that unless it's a string a number can not start with 0.

```js
function getRandomNumber(n){
    var a = [],
        x = ~~(Math.random()*10),
        r = 0;
    while (n) {
      a[x] === void 0 && (a[x] = true, r += x*Math.pow(10,n-1), --n);
      x = ~~(Math.random()*10);
    }
    return r;
}

console.log(getRandomNumber(3));
console.log(getRandomNumber(4));
console.log(getRandomNumber(5));
console.log(getRandomNumber(6));
console.log(getRandomNumber(7));
```

Comment: `~~` a shortcut for `Math.floor()` for positive real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't how to deal with javascript but if it can help you, here a line of scala doing the job

```
def obtainRestrictedRandomNumber(): Long = scala.util.Random.shuffle((0 to 9)).mkString("").toLong
```

What it does is simply generating all digits from 0 to 9 then randomize them, concatenate the Array Int elements into a string for finally casting it into a Long.